# How to get next with JQuery out of ancestor

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want the next 'a' element of current 'a'. When current is 2,3,4 I catch  3,4,5 with a $('a.current').nextAll('a') but when current is 5 i can't catch the next 'a'.
If someones has the solution...

```
<div id="slides">
    <ul>
     <li>
        <a href="" class='current'>2</a>
        <a href="" >3</a>
        <a href="" >4</a>
        <a href="" >5</a>
     </li>
      <li>
        <a href="" >6</a>
        <a href="" >7</a>
        <a href="" >8</a>
        <a href="" >9</a>
     </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You're using `.nextAll`, so you want all the `a` elements that come after the `.current` one, right?

Comment: yes, i just want the first one

Comment: Thanks for all this reply, i don't know exactly which is computationaly the best ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var curr = $('a.current'),            // get the current
    a = curr.closest('ul').find('a'), // get all the "a" elements
    idx = a.index(curr),              // get the index of the current among all
    nextall = a.slice(idx + 1);       // slice those greater than the current
```

***live demo:*** http://jsfiddle.net/eaXdc/

---

If you only wanted the next one, change this:

```
a.slice(idx + 1);
```

to this:

```
a.eq(idx + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var $curr = $('a.current'),
    $next = $curr.next('a');

$next.length || ($next = $curr.parent().next().find('a:first'));
```

Also, you're currently using `nextAll`, which will return ALL of the following `a` elements, when it sounds like you want just the first following `a`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var next = $(this).index() < $(this).parent().children('a').length-1 ? 
           $(this).next() : 
           $(this).parent().next('li').children('a:first');
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/JFgng/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Because `.nextAll()` returns only the siblings of matched elements

6,7,8,9 are not sibling of 5 as they are under different `parent(li)`

You you need those you have to traverse the DOM using jQuery to fetch those `a` elements.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to know that you are at the end (no results), then you should be able to jump out into the next `li` and grab all the subsequent anchor elements.

[Here's how I approached it](http://jsfiddle.net/aYKHy/1/). I gave the fifth anchor element an id to indicate it was my `current`. When your `current` target has no `.nextAll()` children (a `.size()` of 0), you could execute the following to find the subsequent anchor elements.

```
$("#5").parent().next("li").find("a").css("color","grey");​
```

The color change is to assist in indicating which elements were found. Looks like you have lots of options to choose between!

**Update**: If you just want the first one, you could capture it with the `:first` designation like this [update](http://jsfiddle.net/aYKHy/2/).

```
$("#5").parent().next("li").find("a:first")
```